# Weird bug during recursion

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list, tree

I have the following code which builds a binary tree where all nodes are either 0 or 1, so each path from root to leaf is a binary string of a certain length. Initially, my code was just printing all the paths (a path is a list of integers, i.e. [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]). Now I am trying to actually save all paths in a list of list, but I am getting unexpected output. Here is the relevant code:

```
public class Tree{
  Node root;
  int levels;
  LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>> all;

  Tree(int v){
    root = new Node(v);
    levels = 1;
    all = new LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>>();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    Tree tree = new Tree(0);
    populate(tree, tree.root, tree.levels);
    tree.printPaths(tree.root);  // this is the part that prints the paths one by one
    for (LinkedList<Integer> l: tree.all){ // this is when i later tried to save all paths to the
      System.out.println(l);               // list all and then print them out from that list
    }
  }

  
   public void printPaths(Node node)
   {
       LinkedList<Integer> path = new LinkedList<Integer>();
       printPathsRecur(node, path, 0);
   }

  void printPathsRecur(Node node, LinkedList<Integer> path, int pathLen)
    {
        if (node == null)
            return;

        // append this node to the path array
        path.add(node.value);
        path.set(pathLen, node.value);
        pathLen++;

        // it's a leaf, so print the path that led to here
        if (node.left == null && node.right == null){
            printArray(path, pathLen); // Initial version which prints the paths one by one - WORKS FINE
            all.add(path);  // This is when I try to actually keep the paths in a list - doesn't work
        }
        else
        {
            printPathsRecur(node.left, path, pathLen);
            printPathsRecur(node.right, path, pathLen);
        }
    }
...}
```

Essentially, when I was just printing them one by one without saving them, I got the expected output:

```
...
0 1 0 0 1 0
0 1 0 0 1 1
0 1 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 1 0 1
...
```

But when I try to save the paths to a list of lists, and I print each element of that list, I get this:

```
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
...
```

It looks like the list just saves the same super long entry again and again.

Comment: It looks like you write everything in the same list. Read about deep copying in Java. And I would recommend using debugger, it's a really handy tool that will help you better understand how your code works and where it does something not as you planned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't run the code you posted because it's not complete. Might be a good idea to post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and some specific testing data that is exhibiting the "weird" behavior next time.

But from what I can see I would guess that the issue is in the way you are passing the `LinkedList<Integer> path` argument in the `printPathsRecur` method.

You are creating the *path* linked list in the `printPaths()` method. And then you pass a reference to it to the `printPathsRecur()` method. Which modifies the list and then recursively runs itself twice passing the very same reference to the original *path* linked list that you've created back in the `printPaths()` method. Meaning at all times all the recursive calls of the `printPathsRecur()` method are actually working with the very same list that it just keeps adding into, creating a single long list in the *all* 2D linked list. Just many references to the very same linked list.